# Real time slideshow on a website

Tags: ajax, web, real-time

i have a little project in mind for a catwalk fashion where people should be able to connect to a webpage and see the photo of the clothing that it's currently in front of them, so they could click a button saying "I like it" or "I don't like it", and then, somebody behind the stage, click next on the photos so everybody see the next piece of clothing or dress or whatever and repeat.

I wast thinkin of using a simple ajax thread looking to a file which will be changin everytime that the guy who is behind a stage, clicks "next", but i'm thinking: 
It woulndt saturate the server? 
It isn't like a lot of requests for a server?

Imagine like 1000 persons running a thread (like making an ajax call every 5 seconds) to request for the new photo.... is'nt that too much for the server?. I'm asking because maybe there's a better way to do it and i'm not aware of it. Thanks guys!

Comment: Look at Node.js and Socket.io.

Comment: Before asking i found that, but didn't read it, but because you say that, that means that it could be the solution. Thanks man! I'm gonna read more deeply into Socket.io and Node.js.